# Netbeans RCP application not working outside the IDE when built as OS independent zip

Tags: java, swing, javafx, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am building a statistical analysis application on Netbeans RCP for solving tests faster and with less effort https://github.com/PaulMaxAvalosAguilar/Statistikos-Klubas.
The thing is very simple:

1.-There's a module called TrabajosViewer which uses the nodes API to display workspaces where you can organize your samples with some meaningful name, first you create a workspace and then you add some data to it.

2.- You open editor top component which calculates some descriptive satistics stuff for all the sample you entered

3.- All stuff you need for a test is done! Samples are stored in an embedded H2 database(datos module) and results are calculated each time you click on a TrabajosNode.

However when I was testing the app I had to add the following sample:
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AkZmosJJMvdIu3c_IiVkD6JAVVgk (3344 elements); as the app had multithreading capabilities everything was fine, except that after building a release as OS independent zip the app froze from the swing Top Component which was very rare as that wasn't happening on inside Netbeans IDE. I think it has something to see with the build script since I built a Gradle version an everything worked fine https://github.com/PaulMaxAvalosAguilar/Statistikos-Klubas2

Answer (score 2):

If you have an app - any Java app really, not just NetBeans RCP - and it freezes then what you want to do is obtain a **thread dump**. The thread dump will almost always give the clue as to why there's a freeze.

Java has 5 or 6 different ways to obtain a thread dump for a running application (just google it). Out of these methods, the one preferred is the so-called [Ctrl-Break method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr019.html) because it is the one which gives most information. The downside of the method is that you need to have started your application from a console window. But if you can consistently replicate the freeze, then I don't think that's a problem for you. Here's what you would do if you are on Windows:

1. Start `cmd.exe`
2. From the command window, start your application, e.g. `bin\sillyapp64.exe`.
3. Wait for the freeze to happen on your application
4. Now press Ctrl-Break *in the command window*. This will give you a thread dump printed into your command window.
5. Upload the thread dump as part of your question. (or host it somewhere if it is too big)

Instructions for Linux/MacOSX are similar albeit in step 4 you would instead send your process a `QUIT` signal using the kill command.